# UIScrollView within UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have got a hierarchy where UIScrollviews exist within each other.

How may I redirect swipe events for a certain area to an inner scrollview?

Answer (score 2):

If you set your UIScrollViews to only be scrollable in one axis or the other (ie, set their contentSize property appropriately for this. To have a view only be scrollable vertically, set its contentSize.width value to be the same as its bounds.size.width). then they should just work, assuming that no two views scroll in the same axis. Usually, you'll have the 'child' views scroll vertically, and the parent view scroll horizontally.

Comment: The main UIScrollView needs to be scrollable in all directions as it  is zoomable.

Answer (score 1):

If it's at all possible, you should redesign to avoid this.  Safari handles this kind of situation, i.e. iframes and textareas, by having the embedded view scroll with two fingers.  This isn't very discoverable, but it's better than the alternative, which would be even more frustrating.  If an embedded view were just barely onscreen, an attempt to scroll the outer view could instead scroll the inner view, but not display much of anything; it would just appear to be non-responsive.

That said, If you still want to do this, try setting the outer scroll view's `canCancelContentTouches` to `NO`.  This should prevent the outer view from scrolling when a touch begins in the inner view.  Getting Safari-style two finger scrolling would probably involve subclassing `UIScrollView` and implementing the `-touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:` method.