# How to interact with a horizontal scrollview that is a subview of a scroll view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a horizontal scroll view that is a subview of a vertical scroll view. It looks like the vertical scroll view is intercepting all user interactions. I want to be able to scroll horizontally the horizontal scroll view. How would I do this?

Here is a short snippet of my code:

```
  UIScrollView *scrollView2 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,     self.view.width, 100)];

  scrollView2.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width + 400, 100);

  _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.width, 400);

  _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.height - 108)];

[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];

[_scrollView addSubview:scrollView2];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIScrollView within UIScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383487/uiscrollview-within-uiscrollview)

Comment: See @BenGottlieb 's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2383515/91282) in the given dupe.

Comment: Can't seem to get it working. I've included the simple snippet of code in the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass the parent scrollview and override `touchesShouldCancelInContentView:` to return NO whenever the view is child scroll view. i.e;

```
MyScrollView.h

@interface MyScrollView: UIScrollView
@end
```

and in MyScrollView.m

```
@implementation MyScrollView


-(BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)touchedView{
      if(touchedView == _scrollView2){ //Get the reference of that child scroll view here
         return NO;
      }else{
         [super touchesShouldCancelInContentView:touchedView];
      }
}
```

Then your posted code should look like:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView2 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,     self.view.width, 100)];

  scrollView2.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width + 400, 100);



  _myScrollView = [[MyScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.height - 108)];
  _myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.width, 400);


[_myScrollView addSubview:scrollView2];
[self.view addSubview:_myScrollView];
```

Comment: So for example:
Create a subclass of parent scroll view and within this class, add scrollview2 as a subview. Then do something like:

-(BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)touchedView{
      if(touchedView == _scrollView2){
         return NO;
      }else{
         [super touchesShouldCancelInContentView:touchedView];
      }
}

Not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Not subclass the parent view. Make the parent view a subclass of UIScrollVIew. And then do as you told.

Comment: @user2172447: Another thing. You seem to be setting the `contentSize` of `_scrollView` before you initialize it. That won't work. I have updated my answer. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to comment. Hence answering here.

I faced this problem earlier. I do not remember the exact solution. But I think the problem was that you are trying to add the second view controller after the second. I think you should try the reverse.

```
[_scrollView addSubview:scrollView2];
[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];
```